# Persisting new object with nested objects from Spring MVC view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

### Context

There is an application that uses Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA. The JPA provider is Hibernate and the view layer is presented by JSP pages.

There is a page for creating new users. While creating a new user through this page, the user is assigned to a user group (selected from a list). The `User` is new but the selected `Group` already exists at this point. The `User` `@Entity` has a set of `Group` objects in it. The bidirectional association between `User`s and `Group`s is `@ManyToMany` and a table (`group_members`) links these entities.

When the view layer passes a `User` object to the controller, the `setGroups(Set<Group> groups)` method gets called on the `User`. Then this `User` object is persisted through `userDetailsService.add(user)` which is `@Transactional`.

---

### Problem

The `Group`s are loaded into the view when the page is rendered and then they become detached from the persistence unit.
While persisting the `User`, the associated `Group` is detached and the `Group` side is not synchronized with the `User`.
The `User` entity defines utility methods that would synchronize the two sides of the transaction (`addGroup(Group group)` and `removeGroup(Group group)`) but I cannot find a way to make use of them because this way they can only be called outside the transaction which gets created in the service layer.

### Question

What is the best approach to keep all entities in a valid state at all times in this scenario? Should both the User and Group be passed to the service layer?

---

### Code

Some parts were omitted for brevity.

createuser.jsp

```
<body>
<sf:form id="details" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/docreate" modelAttribute="user">

<h2>Sing up</h2>
<table class="formtable">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Userame: </td> <td><sf:input path="username" name="username" type="text" /> <div class="error"> <sf:errors path="username"></sf:errors> </div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Password: </td> <td><sf:input id="password" path="password" name="password" type="password" /> <div class="error"><sf:errors path="password"></sf:errors> </div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Confirm password: </td> <td><input id="confirmpass" name="confirmpass" type="password" /> <div id="matchpass"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="label" align="right">Group</td><td><sf:select id="groups" path="groups" items="${groups}" itemValue="id" 
            itemLabel="groupName"/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td> <td class="button"><input value="Create user" type="submit" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</sf:form>
</body>
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/docreate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreate(Model model, @Validated(FormValidationGroup.class) User user, BindingResult result) {

    // User validation ...
    user.setEnabled(true);

    // Duplicate user check ...
    userDetailsService.add(user);       
    return "usercreated";
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Transactional
public void add(User user) {
    if (!contains(user.getUsername())) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }       
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users",schema="sec")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;    
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;    

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="group_members", schema="sec", joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="group_id") } )
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
    
    // ...
    
    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        this.groups.add(group);
        group.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeGroup(Group group) {
        this.groups.remove(group);
        group.getUsers().remove(this);
    }
    
    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        for (Group group : groups) {
            this.groups.add(group);
        }
    }
}
```

Group.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groups",schema="sec")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String groupName;   
    // ...
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "groups")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    
    // Method to synchronize bidirectional association
    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.users.add(user);
        user.getGroups().add(this);
    }
    
    public void removeUser(User user) {
        this.users.remove(user);
        user.getGroups().remove(this);
    }
    // ...

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users != null ? users : new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As transactions are initiated in the service layer, the only possible choice to implement this synchronization was the

1. service layer OR
2. DAO layer

The service layer defines an `add(user)` method and a `set(user)` method, both of which call the `save(user)` method, hence it was logical to sync the association in the DAO layer which includes that method.
Moreover it seems more appropriate to reference the `EntityManager` in the DAO layer.

```
@Autowired
private GroupRepository groupRepository;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

// ...

public User save (User user) {
    // If the group already exists, then attach it to the persistence context by  getting a reference to it else attach it by saving
    Set<Group> groups = user.getGroups();
    if (!groups.isEmpty()) {
        Set<Group> managedGroups = groups.stream()
                                            .map(group -> group.getId() == 0L ? groupRepository.save(group) : em.getReference(Group.class, group.getId()))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        // Synchronize the bidirectional association
        for (Group group : managedGroups) {
            user.addGroup(group);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Default group
        Optional<Group> result = groupRepository.findByGroupName("USERS");
        if (result.isPresent())
            user.addGroup(result.get());
    }
    // ...
}
```